# A question regarding linear disjiontness and the degree of a field extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K / k$ and $L / k$ be field extensions with $K$ and $L$ linearly disjoint over $k$. Suppose that $K'  / K$ is an extension of finite degree, and that all fields are characteristic zero.

Then is $[K'\cap L : k]$ finite?

Comment: Yes if $L, K$ are algebraic extensions of $k$ (otherwise, please define linear disjointness). Note that $K'\cap L$ is linearly disjoint with $K$ over $k$, so the compositum $(K'\cap L)K$ has degree over $K$ equal to $[K'\cap L : k]$. But $(K'\cap L)K\subseteq K'$.... (this works in any characteristic).

Comment: What is the relationship between $K'$ and the other fields $K$ and $L$? What is "linear disjoint" and are $K$ and $L$ finite? Regardless, if $K'$ is finite, then $K'\cap L \subseteq $K'$, hence finite over $k$.